# Need suggestion to improve plot performance

Tags: matplotlib

I want to plot gold curve from 1980 till today, daily price:

```
gg_gp = getgoldprice()

gold_dates = gg_gp.keys()
gold_values = gg_gp.values()

plt.plot_date(list(gold_dates),list(gold_values),linewidth=1)
```

`gold_dates` contains `datetime` values around 11000 numbers.

I've a problem. Since `gold_dates` does not contain Sat & Sun and days when stock market is closed and I need a continuous curve.

To make it continuous I converted `gold_dates` list to list containing string of the date in format of "yyyy-mm-dd". So now `list(gold_dates)` will contains date strings and I'll use `plt.plot`.

But now it's heavily slowed down. So `plt.plot(list(gold_dates),list(gold_values),linewidth=1)` now simply hangs.

Any suggestions to improve? I'm new to Python so slowly I'll be learning NumPy.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution may be to use an integer sequence as the x variable and then set the ticks and labels manually. Here's a simplified example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gold_dates = ['1980-01-01', '1980-01-02', '1980-01-05']
gold_values = [123, 130, 120]

plt.plot(range(len(gold_dates)), gold_values, linewidth=1)
plt.xticks([0, 1, 2], labels=gold_dates)
```

[image: example plot]

The more powerful solution is to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), which is great at handling time series and has its own plotting functions that are based on matplotlib.